# Dynamic report data table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a app where A report is run once a week.

I have a Report model which manages the report run time etc, and store the generated table name

What I am looking to do is create a new table each time a report is generated.

I have got a controller creating a custom table

I created a random name using table = 'report_'+Digest::MD5.hexdigest(d)
and then reporter = Reporter.new_reporter(table) creates the table

```
def self.new_reporter(table)
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_table(table) do |t|
     t.integer :period, :limit => 4
     t.date :period_start_date
end
```

This successfully creates the table, but the problem is that I can't get the data into this dynamically created table.

I have created a Model called report_table and tried to use ReportTable.table_name = but can't get this to work.

How would I create a new row in a dynamically named/created table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since classes in Ruby are only objects of the type `Class` you can dynamically create them during runtime. So, I imagine something like this should work:

```
# generate the the table name
report_table_name = 'report_'+Digest::MD5.hexdigest(d)

# create the table
Reporter.new_reporter(report_table_name)

# dynamically create a Class object with AR as parent class
# and set the right table name
report_model = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base)
report_model.table_name = report_table_name

# from here on you should be able to invoke any AR method on the dynamic class
report_model.create(period: 1, period_start_date: Time.now.to_date)
```

And to make it more logical you could implement that in your `new_reporter` method so it accepts the table name, creates the table and its according AR class and return it.

But in general I would consider in over thinking your design again. This solution can be slow and obscure, depending on how frequently you use it.

Comment: Thanks didn't know you could dynamically create a class.
I will be running it as a background job and the creation time is less important than the later reporting so I think it will work.

Let me give that a bash!

Comment: Getting there, how do you dynamically set the attr_accessible (rails 3.2.13)?
 I tried report_model.accessible = :all but that fails

Comment: Just had the wrong syntax
corrected - report_model.attr_accessible(:period, :period_start_date)

THANKS!!!